# Calculations with permutations: show that $(1,2,3)^2(5,7)^2=(1,3,2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

How can I show $(1,2,3)^2(5,7)^2=(1,3,2)$? And, specifically, what does $(1,2,3)^2$ and $(5,7)^2$ equal individually?

Comment: Do you understand cycle notation and how to compose the permutations?

Comment: Somewhat. Side question: does any four-element cycle to the fourth power equal the identity (1) too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that with $(5, 7)^2 = (5, 7)(5, 7)$, $\quad (5 \to 7 \to 5)$ and $(7 \to 5 \to 7),\quad $ which gives us $(5, 7)(5, 7) = (1)$, the identity permutation. Any two-cycle, squared, gives us the identity permutation: it's an order two permutation.

Since the first two squared cycles are disjoint from one another, you can simply compute $$(1, 2, 3)^2 \cdot (5, 7)^2 = (1, 2, 3)(1, 2, 3)\cdot(1) = (1, 2, 3)(1, 2, 3) = (1, 3, 2)$$

Comment: As simple as that...+1

Comment: How would you then show (1,2,3)^2=(1,3,2)?

Comment: We have ${\bf 1} \to 2 \to {\bf 3}$, then $3 \to 1 \to {\bf 2}$, (then $2 \to 3 \to 1$, so we're done since the cycle now repeats) and we have $(1, 3, 2)$.

Comment: @amWhy: Clean and concise +1

Answer (score 2):

[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) shows  that you could have other powers in which $$(1, 2, 3)^i \cdot (5, 7)^j = (1, 3, 2)$$ machinery. I examined this by it and you see that $i$ and $j$ could be some other positive integers than $i=j=2$:

```
gap> S7:=SymmetricGroup(IsPermGroup,7);;
     for i in [1..5] do
      for j in [1..5] do
       if (1,2,3)^i*(5,7)^j=(1,3,2) then Print("i=",i,"  ","j=",j,"\n");
       fi;
      od;
     od;
```

---

```
i=2  j=2
i=2  j=4
i=5  j=2
i=5  j=4
```

Comment: I really have to learn GAP! +1

Comment: I really have to get back to using GAP! +1

Comment: @amWhy: But the theoretical taste is really yours here, GAP is like a fast food for us. :-P

Comment: Still, GAP can shed light on problems, and/or confirm "theoretical" work! ;-)